# How to output a vector that is the sum of each slice or page from a 3D array on GPU

Tags: matlab, 3d, parallel-processing, gpu

My process I am trying to accomplish in Matlab:

1. Send a 3D array to the GPU
2. Distribute each slice or 'page' (:,:,i) to a processor on the GPU
3. Output a vector of these summations
4. Return the vector to the CPU

   `% My stab at it:
   Array = gpuArray(ones(3,3,5));
   Array = pagefun(@sum,array);
   Array = gather(Array);
   % Desired output: Array = 1x1x5 vector of 9's`

This throws an error that pagefun does not like the summation function.

On the CPU, a similar process works just fine. It works in a FOR loop as well on the GPU, but this does not vectorize the process for ideal speed. Would a CUDA kernel be more able to do something like this? Is there a better way to do this? Is this more suitable for a cluster rather than a GPU?

Help appreciated, Will

Setup: ASUS i7 quadcore, GTX Geforce 960 running CUDA driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could try out the uglier way:

```
Array = reshape(sum(Array(:,:)), 1, 1, k); %k is whatever third dimension is
```

Comment: You can use `[]` here for the dimension to let `reshape` work it out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and posted it to the matlab forums [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/284112-how-to-output-a-vector-that-is-the-sum-of-each-slice-or-page-from-a-3d-array-on-gpu#answer_222064)

Comment: Answers containing only URLs redirecting to a possible solution are not a best practice in Stackoverflow. If the URL changes, other users with the same problem wont find the solution. Better to elaborate the solution itself in the answer while keeping the URL as source.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer that I also posted on MATLAB answers.

```
array = ones(3, 3, 5, 'gpuArray');
result = sum(reshape(array, [], size(array, 3)));
result = gather(reshape(result, 1, 1, []));
```